# Unhandled JS Exception: Maximum call stack size exceeded in iOS release mode

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native

Description

The application works fine in Debug, but is crashing at start in release mode, after show the splash screen.

Environment
React Native Environment Info:
System:
OS: macOS 10.14.2
CPU: x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4870HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz
Memory: 750.77 MB / 16.00 GB
Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
Binaries:
Node: 9.11.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/bin/node
Yarn: 1.9.4 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm: 6.1.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/bin/npm
Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: iOS 12.1, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.1, watchOS 5.1
IDEs:
Android Studio: 3.2 AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338
Xcode: 10.1/10B61 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
react: 16.4.1 => 16.4.1
react-native: 0.56.0 => 0.56.0
npmGlobalPackages:
create-react-native-app: 2.0.2
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native-git-upgrade: 0.2.7

This is the stack trace

2019-01-15 11:58:46.314666-0300 accomplish[3007:682581] [NetworkInfo] Signal strength query returned error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied", descriptor: 
2019-01-15 11:58:46.512675-0300 accomplish[3007:682785] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2019-01-15 11:58:46.533461-0300 accomplish[3007:682785] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
2019-01-15 11:58:47.662 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Maximum call stack size exceeded.
2019-01-15 11:58:47.662081-0300 accomplish[3007:682774] Maximum call stack size exceeded.
2019-01-15 11:58:47.663 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
2019-01-15 11:58:47.663511-0300 accomplish[3007:682732] Unhandled JS Exception: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
2019-01-15 11:58:47.665138-0300 accomplish[3007:682732] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: Maximum call stack size exceeded.', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: Maximum call stack size exceeded., stack:
c@2:809
@917:660
c@2:809
@13:4146
c@2:809
@12:32
c@2:809
i@2:381
global code@1157:8
'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x192988ec4 0x191b59a40 0x1030d2458 0x1030cff20 0x192990630 0x19286e450 0x19286f034 0x1030e611c 0x10312a7ec 0x10312a548 0x104b63824 0x104b64dc8 0x104b6ce6c 0x104b6db60 0x104b77bfc 0x1925a50dc 0x1925a7cec)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: Please, add more detail about what you are using and what are you trying to achieve. If you can share any code, that will also help identifying the issue.

Comment: @javier did you solve the problem?